# Strongloop Loopback built-in model extension not being called

Tags: loopbackjs

Not sure what I'm missing here.  I am trying to extend the built-in User model in Loopback using the example in their docs:  http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extending+built-in+models#Extendingbuilt-inmodels-ExtendingamodelinJavaScript

The file I created `./common/models/user.js` is never loaded by the application, however, which of course means my extension code is never called.  Any idea on the right way to do this, since the docs are wrong?  Here's what I have at the moment (not that it's relevant since the file is never loaded by the framework):

```
console.log('User.js file being loaded');
module.exports = function(User){
  User.on('attached', function(){
    console.log(User);
  });
};
```

Note that neither console statement fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you complete the model-config.json setup? There will be a `User` entry there already, and you'll need to add a lowercase `user` entry to get your extended model to load.

```
...
// built-in User model
"User": {
  "dataSource": "db"
},
// extends user 
"user": {
  "dataSource": "db"
}
...
```

You also need a `user.json` file that specifies that it will extend the `User` model that's built-in (you can find the built-in `User.json` and .js inside `node_modules/loopback/common/models/`) using `"base": "User"` :

```
{
  "name": "user",
  "base": "User",       // will include all User props
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "pincode": {
      "type": "number"  // only add new props here
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": []
}
```

But I would suggest using a different name other than lowercase user to extend uppercase User since it will be easy to confuse the two. I personally have used `Player` and `Person` (with custom plural `People`) instead of `user`.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up figuring it out after posting this.  From the docs, I'd assumed I could just extend the built-in model with only the things I need and keep using the built-in. i.e. modify-in-place.  You're right, though you really end up creating a whole new model and then never using the built-in except as a prototype.